# error when pushing files to Git in Colab: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Tags: git, google-colaboratory

I was trying to learn github.

I have created a private repository, Repo, on github.

I have created a folder, Folder, with some files in it in Google Drive.

I run the following codes on Google Colab:

```
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/Folder
!git init
!git config --global user.email "JohnSmith@outlook.com"
!git config --global user.name "JohnSmith"
!git add -A 
!git commit -m "first commit"
```

then I tried:

```
!git remote add origin https://<johnsmith>:<password>github@github.com/<johnsmith>/Repo.git
```

from which I got:

```
/bin/bash: johnsmith: No such file or directory
```

then I tried:

```
!git remote add origin https://github.com/johnsmith/Repo.git
!git push -u origin master
```

from which I got:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Note that I change the name of the Repo and usernames for privacy purpose.

So my goal is to put the folder on Google drive in github. How do I do it?

Answer (score 7):

2020 | git v2.17.1

SOLUTION FOR :

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Just do the following step

**1. Generate personal-access-TOKEN for github: from https://github.com/settings/tokens**

2. To push changes do thing till commit as you mentioned then run the following command.

   > git push https://<YOUR-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN>@github.com/<User-Name>/<Repo-Name>.git

---

### example

*add some files or make some changes*

```
!git config --global user.email "JohnSmith@outlook.com"
!git config --global user.name "JohnSmith"
!git add . 
!git commit -m "first commit"
!git push https://123dpope888040e2s90136d8bxx99927@github.com/JohnSmith/hello.git
```